# Merging state-level data to county-level data

Tags: stata

I have dta file that looks like

```
county  state   employment
 1        NY      70
 2        NY      80 
 4        IL      100
 7        IL      60
 3        TX      90
```

Then I have information about state.

```
 state   regulation 
   TX       10
   IL       34
   NY        7
```

How can I combine the data into the dta file?

Simple `merge` and `append` don't seem to work.

Comment: "don't seem to work" is not a problem we can diagnose. What code did you try? What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

load up the first dataset and then

```
merge m:1 state using second_dataset.dta
```